# Modify YAML to include label under each entry in metadata using yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a yaml file like below.This yaml file needs to be patched with a new label  under each configmap.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMapList
items:
  - apiVersion: v1
    data:
      test: 1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: grafana-dashboard-apiserver1
      namespace: monitoring   
  - apiVersion: v1
    data:
      test: 2
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: grafana-dashboard-apiserver2
      namespace: monitoring   
  - apiVersion: v1
    data:
      test: 3
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: grafana-dashboard-apiserver3
      namespace: monitoring
```

I want to insert labels under every configmap in this configmaplist as below,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMapList
items:
  - apiVersion: v1
    data:
      test: 1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: grafana-dashboard-apiserver1
      namespace: monitoring
      labels:
        grafana_dashboard: "1"   
  - apiVersion: v1
    data:
      test: 2
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: grafana-dashboard-apiserver2
      namespace: monitoring   
      labels:
        grafana_dashboard: "1" 
  - apiVersion: v1
    data:
      test: 3
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: grafana-dashboard-apiserver3
      namespace: monitoring    
      labels:
        grafana_dashboard: "1"
```

I am not sure how to do this in bash..Please help me how to do this bash..does yq help? or Kustomize?

Comment: Which version of `yq` are you using? The Wrapper over jq or the Go version? Post output of `yq --version`

Comment: @Inian ..It is yq version 3.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you can use the following path expression to write on all `metadata` fields under the [array of `items`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/path-expressions#arrays-1)

```sh
yq w yaml 'items[*].metadata.labels.grafana_dashboard' --tag '!!str' 1
```

If the YAML output produced is as expected, you can [write in-place](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/commands/write-update#updating-files-in-place) with the `-i` flag i.e. `yq w -i '..'`